# Регистронезависимый поиск в TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

Начинаю изучать Objective-C. Пишу поиск (фильтрацию) TableView через SearchBar.

Кусок кода:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

[filteredArray removeAllObjects];

if (searchText.length == 0)
{
    filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:zakazchikArray];
}
else
{
    NSPredicate * criteria = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"zakazchikName contains %@ OR zakazchikSubcategory contains[c] %@", searchText, searchText];
    [filteredArray addObjectsFromArray:[zakazchikArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:criteria]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Что необходимо дописать в коде, чтобы поиск стал регистронезависимым?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ!

Нужно писать

```
NSPredicate * criteria = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"zakazchikName contains[cd] %@ OR zakazchikSubcategory contains[cd] %@", searchText, searchText];
```